# Distributing k distinct items among r distinct groups without ordering

Tags: combinatorics

> Calculate the number of ways of distributing **k** distinct items among **r**
>   distinct groups such that each group receives at least **a** and at most **b**
>   items **and internal arrangement of items within groups doesn't matter**.

For example suppose there are 2 groups and 3 items A, B, C. The distributions (AB, C) and (BA, C) must not be counted twice.

Or in other words find the number of ways of distributing **k** *distinct* candies to **r** *distinct* kids. Each kid wants atleast **a** and atmost **b** candies. The order in which the kids receive candies doesn't matter.

I've read a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79704/how-to-distribute-k-distinct-items-into-r-distinct-groups-with-each-groups-r). But the solution doesn't satisfy my second condition.

Comment: From answer to similar question, you stated, it seems that answer to this one is also similar. Take generating function that has terms from z^a to z^b.

Comment: but that would correspond to identical candies :/

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand original answer. I think that is reason why exponential generating function is used. Denominator k! means that coefficient at z^k is multiplied by k! to get result. That is same as doing summation for each permutation of k element set.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is Stirling's Number of the Second Kind * r!
So that's:
1/r! * (SUMMATION(j=0 --> r), (-1)^(r-j) * C(r,j) * j^k) * r!
Which simplifies to:
(SUMMATION(j=0 --> r), (-1)^(r-j) * C(r,j) * j^r)

Comment: I should note this only works when each child in your example wants at least one candy and the upper limit on candies is defined by k - r + 1